# node api route doesn't return any status code

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express

I created an api route that register a new user on mongodb.
Currently it doesn't return any status code but I don't know why.

```
const express = require("express");
const User = require("../models/User");
const router = express.Router()

router.post("/users",async (req, res) => {
    
    // Create a user
    const user= new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    });

    // Save user in the database
    user
        .save(user)
        .then(data => {
            
            res.status(200);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message:
                    err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the user."
            });
        });
})
module.exports = router
```

Comment: What do you mean by pending status code?  Also why do you mix async await with promise syntax?

Comment: I edited my question. I didn't notice about the syntax. thanks for the advice.

Comment: So, now you edited/changed your question to change `res.status(200)` to `res.status(200).send({ message: "Success" });`.  That should fix your problem.

Comment: Yes. that solved the error. now  it returns the status code 200.

Comment: So, please put your question back to the way it was originally.  Here on stackoverflow, you do not want to edit the question to include the answer.  Answers belong in answers, not in questions.

Answer (score 1):

`res.status(200)` just sets the status for whenever the response is actually sent.  It does NOT send a response by itself.  So, your server never actually sends the response.  If you want to send a response that is just the status, then use:

```
res.sendStatus(200);
```

Or, just send a response:

```
res.send({ message: "Success" });
```

The default status is already 200 so you don't have to manually set that.